# Weird font kerning issue on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, fonts, chromium

I've been using Chromium from the Ubuntu repository since I switched over to Kubuntu last year, but since Chrome Sync was removed I want to switch over to Google Chrome - however I am having font display problems in Chrome which I don't have in Chromium. Similar issues are also seen in Firefox. I've been searching for an answer but everything I find refers to issues in much older versions of each. In my case fonts display accurately on Chromium but on Chrome and Firefox there is too much space between letters and text on sites like Twitter appears to glitch and pop in. This is worst on Firefox where hovering over a tweet for instance will cause the text to distort, but Chrome has similar distortions especially on loading a page.

[image]

I am using Chromium 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) snap (64-bit), Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) (64-bit), Firefox 86.0 (64-bit) on Kubuntu 20.10.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but for troubleshooting can you try disabling hardware graphics acceleration in Chrome and Firefox to see if that affects it.  Also, are you experiencing the same issue in Libreoffice (in the document, at certain zoom levels)?

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome and Firefox was the first thing I tried, but no luck there. I don't think I am having the same issue in Libreoffice, having checked it just now

Comment: @David it isn't obvious, I think the OP refers to the spacing on certain words, eg. "*Bielfeldt's photography*" on the second line of each

Comment: @David There is an obvious spacing problem (before and after) the letters "f" and "t".

Comment: Try ctrl-shift-R to force a reload from source.  Cache pages seem to have font problems, maybe even a substituted font. I see black triangles become the words "Arrow Drop Down" in some cases for firefox (e.g. tensorflow.org)

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Gunnar's answer, I was able to ameliorate the font kerning issue by commenting out the following passage in `56-kubuntu-noto-conf`:

```xml
  <!-- Roboto is BCI-hinted for widely used LGC characters -->
  <match target="font">
    <test name="family"><string>Roboto</string></test>
    <edit name="hinting" mode="assign"><bool>true</bool></edit>
    <edit name="autohint" mode="assign"><bool>false</bool></edit>
    <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign"><const>hintfull</const></edit>
    <edit name="antialias" mode="assign"><bool>true</bool></edit>
  </match>
```

Still have no clue why this is necessary - in my case I just migrated to 20.04 from 18.04 where this issue was not present. The workaround above seems to work fine for now, however.

Comment: It looks like KDE actually applied this as a fix:https://invent.kde.org/neon/neon/settings/-/commit/b52ae1e91dd3cd0bdf7f11d6d36fde0141be1afc

Comment: If, like me, you came here because Confluence looked bad, this is your fix! (Confluence uses "Roboto" in their CSS)

Comment: This is the fix for Ubuntu Studio as well--instead of 56-kubuntu-noto.conf, the file is 56-ubuntustudio-noto.conf

Answer (score 1):

The default font in Kubuntu is *Noto Sans*. As an experiment you may want to disable the Noto configuration and with that fall back to *DejaVu Sans*:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.avail
sudo mv 56-kubuntu-noto.conf 56-kubuntu-noto.conf.disabled
```

Comment: This seems to solve the issue - would that suggest that there's a problem with my Noto Sans font?

Comment: @ezder: Either the font or the configuration of it. You may want to take a closer look at the file you renamed. Maybe it can be tweaked to work better. Unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to provide more exact guidance.